# Как в php найти все номера телефонов с помощью регулярных выражений?

Tags: php

На python я писал так

```
re.findall(r'>(8|\+7)(\d{10})<', text)
```

Какой аналог этой записи на php?

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('#(8|\+7)(\d{10})#', $text, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
var_dump($out[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

В диалекте регулярных выражений на PHP, альтернативные конструкции можно *(и нужно, если не требуется произвести захват совпавшей подстроки)* записывать в конструкции вида `(?:...)`. Вторая часть вашего шаблона может быть записана без скобок `\d{10}`. В переменной `$arr` будет сохранён массив найденных совпадений:

```
$str = '+74324544467';

preg_match_all('~(?:8|\+7)\d{10}~', $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Если не нужно сохранять совпавшие подстроки, а нужна только проверка на вхождение подстроки в строку, тогда можно этот пример записать так:

```
$str = '+74324544467';

$bool = (bool) preg_match('~(?:8|\+7)\d{10}~', $str);

var_dump($bool);
```

Comment: А как вытащить данные без 8 и +7?

Comment: @Andru как минимум подойдет мой ответ. `var_dump($out[0]);` - полные номера; `var_dump($out[2]);` - без `8 и +7`. P.S. если вам не нужны вообще `8 и 7`, тогда используйте `'#(?:8|\+7)(\d{10})#'` тогда, номера будут тут - `var_dump($out[1]);` (Относительно моего примера).

Comment: Если-же вам нравится ответ выше, то просто нужно добавить группу `\d{10}` заменить на `(\d{10})`, тогда все увидите.